# RSA Container in IIS returning "Object already exists"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, rsa

When I deploy my working *ASP.NET CORE 2.2* app to my local IIS 10 it gives me the exception

```
Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: Object already exists
   at Internal.NativeCrypto.CapiHelper.CreateCSP(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer, SafeProvHandle& safeProvHandle)
   at Internal.NativeCrypto.CapiHelper.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.get_SafeProvHandle()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.get_SafeKeyHandle()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32 keySize, CspParameters parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(CspParameters parameters)
   at SamoletBot.Utilities.RSAHelper.GetRSAFromString(String pemstr) in D:\Projects\SamoletBot22\SamoletBot\SamoletBot.Utilities\RSAHelper.cs:line 23
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
   CspParameters cspParameters = new CspParameters();
   cspParameters.KeyContainerName = "TheContainer";
   cspParameters.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;

   RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey;
   rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParameters);
```

The exception is thrown on the last line

After reading I concluded that this happens because of RSA container permissions and I saw a couple of answers which use this in order to grant permissions to every user.

```
CryptoKeyAccessRule rule = new CryptoKeyAccessRule("everyone", CryptoKeyRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
```

The problem is that `CryptoKeyAccessRule` could not be found. I have imported `using System.Security.AccessControl`. Looking at [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.cryptokeyaccessrule?view=netframework-4.8)  I saw that this is only for .NET Framework.

What is the alternative way to create a "shared" RSA container in .NET Core 2.2?

Comment: Just hit this problem in .NET Core 3.1. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this will fulfil your requirement. But above libs are not included in .net standard/core apis.

You may need to  Switch to below and do a workaround

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl/

```
System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl
```

Comment: I ended up just changing the permissions manually via file explorer. But thank you, may give this a go another time, I’ve awarded you the bounty!